# Logging via debug logs

Tags: apex, visualforce, files, debug-logs

I wanted to ask about debug logs, in my application I need to pass data from Visualforce page to apex class every time I get some message from server. So every time I get a message I call apex function and pass message as parameter, I am able to log my message perfectly but the issue is if I pass these messages individually they will be stored in separate log files.

I want all messages to be logged in a same log file until log file limit is reached and then store next messages in other log file.

Is there any way I can do that? If it is not possible then please suggest a suitable workaround.

Comment: What do you mean by `log file`? Are you creating a document in salesforce to put your logging statement?

Comment: I am referring an instance of debug logs as log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every action from UI/Client is treated as a separate transaction to backend. So that is why you see a new file getting generated everytime.

And just FYI, debug log generation and size is not controlled by our custom code. Its from salesforce end. So no, there is no way to control debug logs.

Comment: I see, could you please elaborate a little on how to create **your own logs and then control that behaviour using File/ Document** ?

Comment: That would involve an external service like java which supports logging services and you would have to do a callout to the service. Let me remove that line as its not directly related to Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Nagendra's answer.

A logging table (a custom SObject) is one approach where each message is written to a row is one workaround.

You don't explain what you are aiming to do overall... Firing a [platform event](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics) per message would add flexibility allowing multiple subscribers to receive the data including external systems and your own UI.

Comment: So what I want is a log file that contain as many messages as it can, so that it will help in understanding of user what events actually happened. 

I am afraid that writing each message to a row will make it difficult for any user to make sense of what happened, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Badar If it is occasional checking of what users do then I'd stick to the standard log files and just search in those for an identifying string.